# break out of iframe buster with exceptions

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have already browsed across few iframe buster codes here....but i'm not able figure out how to create exception for this iframe buster code for certain domains...

```
if (top.location!= self.location) 

{
        top.location = self.location.href
}
```

Comment: If the embedding page is from another domain, then you have no access to its current URL to decide that.

Answer (score 0):

You code will likely fail with access violation on several browsers, but you could try

```
if (document.referer.indexOf("mydomain.com") ==-1 && 
    top.location!= self.location) {
    top.location = self.location.href;
}
```

Note that referer may be empty anyway